# How to use multiple SVGs on a single background centered

Tags: html, css, vue.js, svg

I have 3 svg circles that I want to use as a background. I have a background color and want the 3 circles to be placed within each other and centered on the page. Example: The large circle on the outside, the medium circle inside that and then the small circle inside the medium one. I have included an image to show what I want to achieve.

Using a single svg I can center it using the `justify-content: center;`. I also tried wrapping all 3 svg components with a div element but no success there either.

Project setup: Vue 3, TypeScript, Tailwind css, Css3.

Can anyone help please?

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper bg-gradient-to-b from-green-700 to-blue-500">
    <!--<slot/>-->
    <svg
      width="414"
      height="563"
      viewBox="0 0 414 563"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <circle
        cx="195.44"
        cy="281.56"
        r="255.416"
        stroke="black"
        stroke-opacity="0.02"
        stroke-width="52"
      />
    </svg>

    <svg
      width="414"
      height="437"
      viewBox="0 0 414 437"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <circle
        cx="195.44"
        cy="218.56"
        r="194.578"
        stroke="black"
        stroke-opacity="0.04"
        stroke-width="46"
      />
    </svg>

    <svg
      width="307"
      height="307"
      viewBox="0 0 307 307"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      justify-center
    >
      <circle
        cx="153.44"
        cy="153.559"
        r="137.587"
        stroke="black"
        stroke-opacity="0.05"
        stroke-width="30"
      />
    </svg>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Isn't it simply easier to place all the `<circle>` elements into the same `svg`?

Comment: @Terry If I place all the circles in a single svg then how would i specify the height for each circle ?

Comment: @Terry should I then adjust on the cx and cy values?

Comment: The size of the circle is determined by its radius, which is `r`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Terry As Terry suggested, I placed all 3 circle elements inside a single svg. I then used the cx and cy properties to position the circles accordingly.